# Proving the equation has no root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

How to show that for $a\in \mathbb R$, the equation $x^2+12a^2+4ax-8a+8=0$ has no root?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you prove no real roots, in Fact we have

$$(x+2a)^2+8a^2-8a+8=(x+2a)^2+8\left(a-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+6>0$$

proof 2:
$$\Delta =16a^2-4(12a^2-8a+8)=-32a^2+32a-32=-32\left(a-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2-24<0$$

Comment: I believe you mean, "If you *mean*..."

Comment: Can you explain for your answer? I don't understand

Comment: @Mathxx What's not to understand? He rewrote the expression into a sum of two squares and one positive number, and this number is obviously always greater than $0$, so there cannot be a root.

Comment: Where did that solution come from?  OP must be new to algebra.  What does the triangle mean?

Comment: This is basic high school stuff, and students usually are taught pretty early in this about the discriminant, with $\;\Delta\;$ notation or without it, and its meaning about real roots' existence. If the OP doesn't know that this is an excellent time for her/him to sit on books/notes and learn it. Good answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

Its reduced discriminant is $$\Delta'=4a^2-(12a^2-8a+8)=-8(a^2-a+1)<0$$
as $\,a^2-a+1$ has no real roots (its roots are the complex cubic roots of $-1$). Alternatively, completing the square you can show $\,a^2-a+1\ge \dfrac34$.

Comment: Hello,the same as proof 2 Haha

Comment: A little shorter if you just stick to complex roots :o). Actually I forgot to check if  an answer had been posted while I was writing mine. I can delete it if you want.

Comment: @Bernard No, leave it. It isn't identical with the other answer, and this is so basic and standard a subject that there is not much room, apparently, for new things. The OP also seems to be pretty new to these things so any slightly different approach is likely to be hlepful.